# C++Builder Excel TExcelWorksheet Set Tab Color

Tags: c++builder

In C++Builder using Office 2000 Automation classes is there a way to set the tab color on the current worksheet (TExcelWorksheet* ExcelWorksheet)?

Comment: In Delphi I would write (assuming WorkSheet: ExcelWorksheet;) e.g.: `WorkSheet.Tab.Color := clBlack;`

Comment: Hi Tom - what I have worked out is that by searching "when did excel allow colored tabs" is "This functionality was introduced in Excel 2002 and is not available in Excel 97 or Excel 2000. Changing the color of your worksheet tabs can help you to quickly identify particular worksheets."
I switched to using ExcelXP and voila - the Tab property showed up. I am guessing that the same will be true for C++Builder also.

Comment: Mark, sorry for not paying attention to the version you asked about! I can not currently test with C++Builder, so assuming the library is similar I only wrote a comment how to do it in Delphi.